# Is there a way to turn off the blue highlighting when using PDF-TEX Sync? I find it is a hindrance when initially viewing the pdf

Tags: pdftex

In PDF-TeX Sync is there a way to turn off the blue highlighting? I find it is a hindrance when initially viewing the pdf file

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This seems to be something your latex editor does, so you should look in the settings there and mention which editor you are using.

Comment: what software are you asking about, what blue highlight? pdftex adds no colour to anything by default.